# Elasticsearch: obtaining each field score in the same document

Tags: elasticsearch

Assuming I have a document with three fields: `name`, `company`, `email`  each one mapped with edge-ngram

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "company": "John's company",
  "email": "johndoe@gmail.com" 
}
```

When searching for "john" I want to be able to get each field score individually

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { "match": { "name": "john" }},
        { "match": { "company": "john" }},
        { "match": { "email": "john" }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In this example the score from each `match` clause is added together, then divided by the number of `match` clauses. So is there anyway to obtain the score from each `match` clause individually not just the final score for the whole document?

I think setting **"explain": true** is also not ideal since it provides very low-level details of scoring (inefficient and difficult to parse).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch recently added the ability to return the score of named queries in [#94564](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/94564)

We can use named queries to track which queries matched returned documents and return the score for each named query by setting the request parameter named [`include_named_queries_score`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html#named-queries) which controls whether scores associated with the matched queries are returned or not.

The final query would look like this:

```json
GET /_search?include_named_queries_score
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { "match": { "name": { "query": "john", "_name": "name" } } },
        { "match": { "company": { "query": "john", "_name": "company" } } },
        { "match": { "email": { "query": "john", "_name": "email" } } }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of a way that you could do this without modifying the search results.

However if you were to use a different boost on each field you might be able to reverse your way into determining the value of each.   For instance boosting one field by 1 the next by 10 and the final by 100, and examining the final number might give you what you are looking for, however the field boosted by 100 will be the only one that matters.

Curious the application of this, as it seems boosting in general might solve what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't think boosting would help that much (correct me if I'm wrong). what I want to do is to implement autocomplete where I always show only two fields the first one is the `name` field and the second one is the highest field score between all other fields. for example if the user searched for "john" I will always show `name` field and choose the highest field score between `email` `company` `phone`  `website`  fields whichever has the highest score will be shown along with `name` field.

Comment: The thought was to use boost as a bit map if you will so that the score range for each field would be forced into a different range of numbers.

for instance if a = 1 b=2 c=3
and I want to compact that into a single value I could use
x = a*10000+b*100+c
where the result is 1002003, which I could then mod and reverse using my coefficients, the coefficients would be your boost values.   I am not certain what normalization happens underneath with score so this may just not be possible.

Comment: It was just a thought that came to me that might be possible, so I shared, definitely not a known solution